# Resizing JPopupMenu and avoiding a "flicker" issue

Tags: java, swing, menu, paint, repaint

I am trying to implement a search results popup list similar to the style found here:

http://www.inquisitorx.com/

(I'm not trying to implement a Google search, I'm just using this as a rough example of the style I'm working on.)

In any event, I am implementing this by using a `JList` contained within a `JPopupMenu` which is popped up underneath a `JTextField`.

When a user enters search terms, the list changes to reflect different matching results. I then call `pack` on the `JPopupMenu` to resize it. 
This works, however, it creates a slight flicker effect since it is actually hiding the popup and showing a popup. (See the private method `getPopup` in `JPopupMenu` where it explicitly does this.)

Is there any way to just get it to just resize itself (aside from using a `JWindow`)?

Comment: In the end, I ended up using a JWindow. It may be heavywight, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `setSize()`? It looks like that gets handled in `JComponent` and might avoid the repaint issues.

I think the issue that `getPopup` is addressing is what to do when the dimensions of the popup will not fit within the window. When that happens, it drops back from a lightweight component to a heavyweight and that definitely requires a hide and show. So, I think if you can guarantee your popup won't extend beyond the window the setSize might do the trick.

Comment: Based on what I read in Sun's code, I beleive you are correct. It uses the PopupFactory to get a popup object which returns light/medium/heavyweight versions depending on the case.
There is a setPopupSize method but it also calls the same getPopup method.

Comment: Using setSize resulted in other undesirable paint issues.

Answer (score 2):

to me work :

**popup.pack();**

**popup.validate();**

this work in linux with java version "1.6.0_34". I don't know is that work on windows.

Answer (score 1):

The setSize() method didn't work in my case. The popup.pack() approach did work, but also resulted in a flicker. The best solution that I have found was the one found [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/5706787#5706787). In short:

```
    Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(popupMenu);
    window.pack();
    window.validate();
```